# How can I bold text within an object array items string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, object

I am using the data from below to pass as props in React. Everything works fine but I need to only bold the words "target audience" in the text property. Is there a way to do this?

```
const SlideData = [
{
    index: 1,
    title: "Target Audience",
    text: [
      "The target audience for this course is anyone who is assigned roles as a HR Employee Maintainer...",
    ],
    image: {
      src: targetAudience,
      width: imageSize,
    },
},
    index: 2,
    title: "Reporting ",
    text: [
      "Reporting Manager is designated to...",
    ],
    image: {
      src: reporting,
      width: imageSize,
    },
},
]

export default SlideData
```

Added Render Component

```
const TextSlide = ({ title, text = [], list, image }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="slide">
        <div className="standard-grid">
          <span className="slide-title title">{title}</span>
          <div className="content">
            {text.map((t, i) => (
              <p key={i} className="text">
                {t}
              </p>
            ))}
          </div>
          {image ? <img className="picture" src={image.src} style={{ maxWidth: image.width }} alt="image" /> : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TextSlide;
``
```

Comment: How do you render the text?

Comment: Bold text relates to presentation while your `SlideData` relates to, well, data; you should try to avoid as much as possible mixing the two layers. Anyway, a way you could handle the issue is to use a markdown-like approach and change `"The target audience for this course is ..."` with something like `"The #target audience# for this course is ...`, then replace the `#` with the relevant tags during in the render.

Comment: I added where it renders if that helps

Comment: well I definitely would prefer not to mix them @secan , I thought about maybe creating a const that holds a bolded string "target audience"  and then import it into the text: property via string literal? but then I would have quite a few of those..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the text to an object with a key of `__html` and use *bold* tags to render it by using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
const SlideData = [
  {
    index: 1,
    title: "Target Audience",
    text: [
      {
        __html:
          "The <b>target audience<b> for this course is anyone who is assigned roles as a HR Employee Maintainer...",
      },
    ],
    image: {
      src: targetAudience,
      width: imageSize,
    },
  },
];

const TextSlide = ({ title, text = [], list, image }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="slide">
        <div className="standard-grid">
          <span className="slide-title title">{title}</span>
          <div className="content">
            {text.map((t, i) => (
              <p key={i} className="text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={t} />
            ))}
          </div>
          {image ? (
            <img
              className="picture"
              src={image.src}
              style={{ maxWidth: image.width }}
              alt="image"
            />
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is a small [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/PomdmmV) for demonstration.

Comment: ×
Error: `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` must be in the form `{__html: ...}`. Please visit https://reactjs.org/link/dangerously-set-inner-html for more information. I get this error?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you do not need the `t.__html`. Just pass `t`. It automatically reads the key and applies it. I will update my answer.

Comment: Ok, does every element in `text` have a key name `__html`?

Comment: it does now but no dice. it actually doesnt show errors but doesnt display anything. every object looks like this : {
    index: 2,
    title: "Target Audience",
    text: [
      {
        _html:
          "The <b>target audience<b> for this course is anyone who is assigned roles as a HR Employee Main...",
      },
    ],
    image: {
      src: targetAudience,
      width: imageSize,
    },
  },

Comment: <p key={i} className="text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={t.__html} /> this doesnt show errors, but its not setting the inner html?

Comment: It has to look like this: `<p key={i} className="text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={t} />`. What should happen is that the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop consumes the `__html` key. If you pass it like in your example, it will look for the key, but does not find it.

Comment: So i commented out to just one object and it works!, however If I add another it gives me the error, so I duplicated the same object and it works so Im guessing I was just writing my data wrong. I could have swore it was exact but my eyes must have deceived me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could split the text by target audience, and map the chunks inbetween to text nodes appending a  node to each element:

```
      "The target audience for this course is anyone who is assigned roles as a HR Employee Maintainer...",
       .split("target audience")
       .map((text, index) => <>{index !== 0 && <b>target audience</b>} {text}</>)
```

A more sophisticated approach would be to inject html tags into the text, and use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html):

```
 const formatted = text.replace(/(target audience)/g, it => `<b>${it}</b>`);

 return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={formatted} />;
```

Comment: I am started to understand, I edited to add my render method if that helps. What would you recommend after viewing that?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
text: ["The ", <strong>target audience</strong>, " for this course is anyone who is assigned roles as a HR Employee Maintainer..."]
```

React will render this as a string with the HTML tags applied.

Comment: Pretty sure that will just render the tags as strings?

Comment: Nope, it renders as a string with the tags applied.  I believe React takes care of it under the hood.  Seems like a simpler solution than all the JavaScript

Comment: Am I wrong? I tested it in React and it seems to work..

Comment: i couldnt get it to work in mine unfortunately :(